# Eclipse deletes the src file content on importing a android project in it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am importing an example project for using an image cropping library on android. When I look into the src file of that project there exist a MainActivity.java file 
 [image: src file]

but when I import this project in eclipse, then eclipse shows that src file is empty. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem in import.
First open eclipse -> File -> Import -> Choose Android -> Existing android code in workspace then follow the steps to the end.

If this does not works then copy the folder and try it from another drive.

And make sure the workspace does not contain the same file.

Comment: I have done all these basic things like 1) switching the workspace. 2)Changing the drive. 3) Restarting the eclipse.  etc etc..

Comment: can you give me the download link please.

Comment: this is for you.     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzftcdTJ6R7ta2t1UWcxbDhjY2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop     you can download it from here. Actually someone gave me this library.